# How is it possible inline base64 data uri (image) is cached?

Tags: html, css, image, performance, caching

I am using as background image a data uri base64 encoded image directly inline inside the HTML page.
I read everywhere that contrary to unencoded images, they're not stored in cache , which is indeed sometimes a performance problem.

But when looking at my chrome dev tools, I see "cached in memory"...

[image]

Are inlined-in-the-html base64 image cached ?

If yes : my question is: I checked it originally because i wanted to analyze the time to load the base64 inlined-image. So i am unable now to see on first download/visit the time spend to decode and load it? I tried clearing my browser history but contrary to other caches (like standard assets like images), it remains, that is to say even if i clear my browser history/caches, the next time I load it, it still is written in chrome dev tools as 0ms/"from memory cache": how can I clear it to see what happens for first time visitors ?

Note: Of course "disable cache' is selected inside chrome dev tools .
Also, I am not sure it is important but here is the base64 and html code (it's pretty small: less than 900 bytes)

```
<div style="background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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');" ><a href="/home">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I repeat your test Chrome makes two requests. The first one fetches the HTML page and is a normal request. The second fetches the image and is served from memory. That makes sense as the image was included in the first request embedded in the HTML itself.

In other words inlined images are not cached unless the page they live in is cached.

Comment: So you're saying the inline base64 is cached because the HTML file it lives in is cached. But  can html page be cached ? I thought only image, css,js can be cached?

Comment: When I say image,cc, js can be cached I meant images,css and js that are not inside the HTML file (inline) but live in an external file (.css, .js files...)

Comment: For the first request it is probably wrong to talk about cached, but no separate request is performed for the inlined resource so Chrome lists it as being served from "memory cache". In answer to your question anything can be cached, certainly HTML pages. However, dynamically generated pages typically set headers that prevent them from being cached and most pages nowadays are dynamic. So, inlined resources are a double-edged sword!